# Nivo Slider's absolute positioning sticks to browser window instead of scrolling with design in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, positioning, absolute, nivo-slider

People are still using IE7 and pointed out to me that my Nivo Slider on the home page sticks to the browser window and does not stay positioned in the design when scrolling vertically in Internet Explorer 7. There are many suggestions online that solve similar problems but not this one. Could someone take a look at http://mileslostmilesgained.org and help?

Answer (score 0):

i saw that your problem, one small things  you remove the height:100%  in the body tag.

main.css (line 3).

then you get the answer.